# A form of the mean and variance of the Beta distribution and binomial distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

Suppose $\alpha,\beta\ge 0.$
\begin{align}
\text{Let } & p = \frac \alpha {\alpha+\beta}, & q & = \frac \beta {\alpha+\beta}, \\[10pt]
& n = \alpha+\beta+1, \\[10pt]
\text{So that } & p+q=1 \\[4pt]
\text{and } & \alpha = (n-1)p, & \text{and } \beta & = (n-1)q.
\end{align}

- Suppose $X$ is the proportion of successes in $n$ independent trials with probability $p$ of success on each trial, so that $nX\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$ and $\Pr(0\le X\le 1) = 1.$
- Suppose $Y\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta),$ so that $\Pr(0\le Y\le 1) = 1.$

Then
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{E}(X) = \operatorname{E}(Y) = np & = \frac \alpha {\alpha+\beta}, \\[12pt]
\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{var}(Y) = \frac{pq} n & = \frac{\left( \dfrac \alpha {\alpha+\beta} \right) \left( \dfrac \beta {\alpha+\beta} \right)}{\alpha+\beta+1}.
\end{aligned} \qquad \right\} \tag 1
\end{equation}

Is there some point to paying attention to this commonality between these two families of distributions? Might it give us a central-limit-theorem-like result on a continuous approximation to a discrete distribution? And if it did, could that be used for something?

And has anyone ever said or written anything about this in public?

Comment: in bayesian stats the beta distribution is a conjugate priori for the binomial distribution. Moreover you may be interested to have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/relationship-between-binomial-and-beta-distributions, and to the 2nd answer too

Comment: @fonfonx : I've massaged your comment for a while. Suppose $P\sim\operatorname{Beta} (\alpha,\beta)$ and $nX \mid P \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, P),$ with $n=\alpha+\beta+1$ as above (so that $\alpha+\beta$ must be an integer). I've worked out $\operatorname{var}(nX)$ and I'm not sure the result sheds light. $\qquad$